# Where is "uname" pulling information from?

Tags: command-line, kernel

Where is `uname -i` pulling the information from?

Do the details exist in `/etc/`?

Do the details exist in `/proc/`?

If so, which file is it referencing to output those details?

Comment: Related: [where does uname get its information from](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/137052/49439)

Answer (score 31):

`uname` uses the system call `uname(2)` to get the kernel related information it shows.

The synopsis is:

```
#include <sys/utsname.h>
int uname(struct utsname *buf);
```

where `uname(2)` returns information in the structure pointed to by `buf`. Also you can read the header file `utsname.h` from `/usr/include/"$(arch)"-linux-gnu/sys/utsname.h` to dig deeper.

Have a look at `man 2 uname` to get more idea about this.

Comment: when I run "uname -i", the output is "x86_64".  When I cross reference "/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/sys/utsname.h", I don't see anything that references "x86_64".  I referenced the "man 2 uname" and it states that part of utsname information is referenced via "/proc/sys/kernel/{ostype}, {hostname}, {osrelease}, {version} and {domainname}"  the problem is that none of those files reference anything stating "x86_64".  Any other recommendations?

Comment: @RoyHernandez Whats the output of `locate --regex '^/usr/include/.*/sys/utsname.h$'`?

Comment: The output is: "/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/sys/utsname.h
"

Comment: @RoyHernandez This tells that the file does exist and you were doing something wrong..

Comment: When I run a ``uname -i`` the output is ``x86_64``.  When I run ``locate --regex '^/usr/include/.*/sys/utsname.h$'`` the output returns ``/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/sys/utsname.h``

Comment: @RoyHernandez so, i don't get it..whats wrong with `/usr/include/"$(uname -i)"-linux-gnu/sys/utsname.h` ?

Comment: I am not sure.  I am just trying to figure out where ``uname -i`` is gathering it's output and it seems to be verify difficult.

Answer (score 22):

The program `strace` allows us to view the system calls an application may make. With `uname -a` it's apparent that the only `open` calls go to system libraries, so technically there is no file on the filesystem that the `uname` opens for reading. Rather it makes system calls using the C libraries.

As heemayl properly pointed out there exists sys call to retrieving  the information stored in the `uname` structure. It's man page, suggests the following:

> This is a system call, and the operating system  presumably knows  its
>          name,  release  and  version . . .
>    . . .  Part of the utsname information is also accessible  via  /proc/sys/ker‐
>          nel/{ostype, hostname, osrelease, version, domainname}.
>
> Part of the utsname information is also accessible  via 
>   /proc/sys/ker‐    nel/{ostype, hostname, osrelease, version,
>   domainname}.

`/proc` filesystem however is virtual, meaning it exists only while the OS is running. Thus to some extend it is set within kernel or system libraries.

Finally, reading through  the source code of `uname.c` which can be obtained with `apt-get source coreutils` , we can see that it indeed uses  the `utsname.h` library(printed with line numbers):

```
 19 
 20 #include <config.h>
 21 #include <stdio.h>
 22 #include <sys/types.h>
 23 #include <sys/utsname.h>
 24 #include <getopt.h>
 25
```

`strace` output:

```
skolodya@ubuntu:$ strace uname -a
execve("/bin/uname", ["uname", "-a"], [/* 58 vars */]) = 0
brk(0)                                  = 0x1478000
access("/etc/ld.so.nohwcap", F_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
mmap(NULL, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7efee6935000
access("/etc/ld.so.preload", R_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/etc/ld.so.cache", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=137226, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 137226, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE, 3, 0) = 0x7efee6913000
close(3)                                = 0
access("/etc/ld.so.nohwcap", F_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\2\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0>\0\1\0\0\0\320\37\2\0\0\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=1840928, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 3949248, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x7efee6350000
mprotect(0x7efee650b000, 2093056, PROT_NONE) = 0
mmap(0x7efee670a000, 24576, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x1ba000) = 0x7efee670a000
mmap(0x7efee6710000, 17088, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7efee6710000
close(3)                                = 0
mmap(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7efee6912000
mmap(NULL, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7efee6910000
arch_prctl(ARCH_SET_FS, 0x7efee6910740) = 0
mprotect(0x7efee670a000, 16384, PROT_READ) = 0
mprotect(0x606000, 4096, PROT_READ)     = 0
mprotect(0x7efee6937000, 4096, PROT_READ) = 0
munmap(0x7efee6913000, 137226)          = 0
brk(0)                                  = 0x1478000
brk(0x1499000)                          = 0x1499000
open("/usr/lib/locale/locale-archive", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=7216688, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 7216688, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE, 3, 0) = 0x7efee5c6e000
close(3)                                = 0
uname({sys="Linux", node="eagle", ...}) = 0
fstat(1, {st_mode=S_IFCHR|0620, st_rdev=makedev(136, 0), ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7efee6934000
uname({sys="Linux", node="eagle", ...}) = 0
uname({sys="Linux", node="eagle", ...}) = 0
write(1, "Linux eagle 4.1.0-040100rc2-gene"..., 113Linux eagle 4.1.0-040100rc2-generic #201505032335 SMP Mon May 4 03:36:35 UTC 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
) = 113
close(1)                                = 0
munmap(0x7efee6934000, 4096)            = 0
close(2)                                = 0
exit_group(0)                           = ?
+++ exited with 0 +++
```

Comment: when I run "uname -i", the output is "x86_64".  When I cross reference "/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/sys/utsname.h", I don't see anything that references "x86_64".  I referenced the "man 2 uname" and it states that part of utsname information is referenced via "/proc/sys/kernel/{ostype}, {hostname}, {osrelease}, {version} and {domainname}"  the problem is that none of those files reference anything stating "x86_64".  Any other recommendations?

Comment: @RoyHernandez In C it's possible to determine architecture of a CPU based on the size that integer takes , for instance - refer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1288189/3701431). So the `uname.c` doesn't necessarily need to use a library for that -  we can look at the source code, of course, to be sure.

Comment: Actually, it does rely on a library . . . `machine.h`

Comment: ``machine.h`` seems to be peppered throughout the system.   Which ``machine.h`` file does it rely on?

Comment: @RoyHernandez all the listed `machine.h` on my system seem to be in the `/usr/src/linux-headers-3.19.0-33` directory. It's very likely that it uses the library provided by the currently running kernel

Comment: I am not sure...  I don't see a ``machine.h`` on my computer within the ``/usr/src/linux-headers-3.19.0-33`` directory.   I am not sure how to cross reference the output of ``uname -i``.

Comment: How about this ? `find /usr/src/linux-headers-$(uname -r)/include/ -name "machine.h"`

Comment: Let me actually read the source of `uname.c` a bit more, and I'll get back to you later once i figure this out.

Comment: ``find /usr/src/linux-headers-$(uname -r)/include/ -name "machine.h"`` output is ``/usr/src/linux-headers-3.19.0-47-generic/include/config/stop/machine.h``

Answer (score 6):

Of course heemayl's answer is correct.

Just for fun, here's a working C snippet showcasing the data returned by `uname()` (a sort of a homemade `uname` if you want): compile it with `gcc uname.c -o uname` and run it with `./uname`:

```c
#include <stdio.h> // printf()
#include <sys/utsname.h> // uname()

int main() {
        int ret; // stores the return value of uname()
        struct utsname utsname; // stores the data returned by uname()
        struct utsname *utsname_ptr = &utsname; // pointer to the struct holding the data returned by uname()

        ret = uname(utsname_ptr); // calls uname() on utsname_ptr and stores its return value in ret

        /* prints the fields of utsname */

        printf("%s\n", utsname.sysname);
        printf("%s\n", utsname.nodename);
        printf("%s\n", utsname.release);
        printf("%s\n", utsname.version);
        printf("%s\n", utsname.machine);

        /* returns the return value of uname() */

        return(ret);
}
```

```
% ./uname 
Linux
user-X550CL
4.2.0-25-generic
#30-Ubuntu SMP Mon Jan 18 12:31:50 UTC 2016
x86_64
```

Comment: where is the ``printf("%\n", utsname.machine);`` pulling it's information from?

Comment: @RoyHernandez From the struct `utsname`, which is populated during the call to `uname()`. The example probably it's not too straightforward to someone without C basics, but here's more or less what happens: a `struct` (C data type) of type `utsname` named `utsname` (type defined in `<sys/utsname.h>`) is declared; then a pointer to it named `utsname_ptr` is declared (since `uname()` accepts a pointer to a `struct` of type `utsname` as an argument, though this could have been avoided in this case, but that's another story).

Comment: Then the call to `uname()` has the effect of populating the struct `utsname`, which at the time of the `printf()` call contains the various values inside the various fields. Unluckily if you are not familiar with C this is probably not going to be easy to grasped in detail, but the point is that `uname()` populates a data structure built on purpose, whose fields are later printed via `printf()`.

Answer (score 4):

As an addition to heemayl's answer, you can get some information like in the `uname` command from `/proc/version`.

Comment: /proc/version contains "Linux version 3.19.0-47-generic (buildd@lgw01-19) (gcc version 4.8.2 (Ubuntu 4.8.2-19ubuntu1) ) #53~14.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Mon Jan 18 16:09:14 UTC 2016"  and "uname -i" output is "x86_64".