# Release name of current signed kernel

Tags: kernel, uefi

Is the output of `uname -r` always like `4.2.0-37-generic`, or would it show the postfix `.efi.signed` denoting it is a signed kernel, if a signed kernel is booted on a machine (with UEFI) requiring such a kernel?

The output of `linux-version list` shows this postfix for signed kernels.

Comment: I'd like to understand this better too. Suggestion for testing: turn on secure boot. Can you boot? Does `uname -r` now show the postfix? When I get kernel updates, I see both non signed and signed vmlinuz files etc. I'm not at my uefi machine so can't test it myself

Comment: @Zanna I do not have one either, but if I install a signed image, `linux-version list` and `ls -l /boot/vmlinuz-*` shows an item that has '.efi.signed' postfix, not '-signed' postfix.

Comment: I do have one, I will test it later (although I have no interest in using secure boot which is FUD IMO) and let you know what happens

Comment: `linux-version list` reads `/boot` for `vmlinuz*` files. I was able to learn [where uname gets its information](http://askubuntu.com/questions/724415/where-is-uname-pulling-information-from) - directly from the running kernel via a system call. Therefore, if vmlinuz-4.4.0-22-generic-efi-signed is booted, `uname -r` should output `4.4.0-22-generic-efi-signed`. This is logical, but so far I can't verify it by experiment, because although I have that image in /boot, it has no initrd.img, is not an option in GRUB menu, and if I turn on secure boot, I cannot get past BIOS.

Comment: @Zanna at least in Ubuntu 14.04, the postfix for signed vmlinuz files in /boot/ is `.efi.signed`not `-efi-signed`.

Comment: Oh maybe same for me, I was just typing it off the top of my head. Whatever it is, logically uname will give the whole string, I can't think of a reason why part of it would be omitted in the special case of it being signed.

Comment: @Zanna I tested on a fiend's new computer that has signed kernels installed (apparently by default besides regular kernels). `uname -r` does not show any additional postfix, nor the signed kernels are listed separately in GRUB menu.

Answer (score 0):

The output of `uname -r` depends on the topmost `Makefile` of your kernel source. You can edit it. For example, the `Makefile` in your case would look like this.

```
VERSION = 4
PATCHLEVEL = 2
SUBLEVEL = 0
EXTRAVERSION = -37-generic
```

You can change the `EXTRAVERSION` field, to change the output of `uname -r`